# Premiere Pro reactive audio wave form?

Tags: audio, video-editing, editing, adobe-premiere

I have been checking out premiere pro and am baffled to see that there is no reactive audio waveform as shown in the image below.

[image]

The audio waveform in the timeline in premier stays the same even if the audio bar is lowed or taken all the way up.

There must have been some reason why such an expensive and popular software does not have this, or maybe there is a way to turn it on in the settings that I am not aware of.

Do let me know if this is a setting and can be turned on.

Comment: Pro Audio apps don't do that, it's a video app thing - notably FCP & iMovie. Might be simply a design choice, though I've never used it so idk if there's a pref.

Comment: Camtasia which is a screen recording app has it, filmora has it which is a video editing tool as well. Figured premiere pro would have it ‍♂️